# Active Directory - Django/Rails

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, active-directory

I'm thinking about re-writing a web app in Django or Rails and wondering about authenticating against AD. Is one ecosystem better suited for this (libraries, etc) or is it  a toss-up?

(The app will be hosted on Linux)

I have lots of reasons for the re-write, one them is to make myself more marketable. Anyone care to comment on the which of these frameworks has better long-term outlook for a new programmer? (I've read the StackOverflow threads already, but ask just in case something new has come up).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

A quick google to give you some pointers on using Active Directory in these environments.

- http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/501/
- http://www.zorched.net/2007/06/04/active-directory-authentication-for-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I'd seen the Django implementation but missed the Rails one you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I did Active Directory auth in Rails about a year ago. I did it similarly to the article Daniel linked to. It felt hacky, but it was an internal app, so it was acceptable.

Since then [Passenger](http://www.modrails.org/) (`mod_rails`) has come out which could be a better alternative than FastCGI.